# Search JSON data and display in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this JSON file, how can I search it by `name` using a searchfield/input/searchbox? Like when i hit a "Search" button, the results matching the search term will display in a `div` one after another

```
[
  {
   "name": "Senior Officer Trade Back Office",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/senior-officer-trade-back-office-1061445-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=1&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "Junior Officer Trade Back Office",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/junior-officer-trade-back-office-1061443-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=2&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "5 Machine Learning",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/5-machine-learning-1061442-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=3&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "3 Ruby Developers",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/3-ruby-developers-1061441-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=4&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sales Staff (Losgistic - Salary Attractive)",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/sales-staff-losgistic-salary-attractive-1061440-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=5&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "5 Front-End Developers",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/5-front-end-developers-2-1061439-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=6&sortBy=date"
  }
]
```

This is one of those Im-new-to-JQuery-so-please-show-mercy, thanks

I tried: (this is instant search `keyup` )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li>');
    }
   });   
  });
 });

 $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
 });
});
```

Comment: please show us what you tried?

Comment: [Right now, your question looks like a „can I haz codes?“-question](https://can-i-haz.codes) what is off-topic on SO. Either follow the steps on the first link, read **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** or visit **[the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**. Good luck!

Comment: @brk updated, please take alook

Comment: @CodeF0x updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that, what you mean?:

```js
const srcData = [
  {
   "name": "Senior Officer Trade Back Office",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/senior-officer-trade-back-office-1061445-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=1&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "Junior Officer Trade Back Office",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/junior-officer-trade-back-office-1061443-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=2&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "5 Machine Learning",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/5-machine-learning-1061442-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=3&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "3 Ruby Developers",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/3-ruby-developers-1061441-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=4&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sales Staff (Losgistic - Salary Attractive)",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/sales-staff-losgistic-salary-attractive-1061440-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=5&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
   "name": "5 Front-End Developers",
   "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/5-front-end-developers-2-1061439-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=6&sortBy=date"
  }
]
document.getElementById('searchfield').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  let pattern = new RegExp(this.value, 'i');
  let resultSet = srcData.filter(item => item.name.match(pattern) && this.value != '').map(item => `<a href="${item.url}">${item.name}</a>`).join(', ');
  document.getElementById('searchresult').innerHTML = resultSet;
});
```

```css
#searchresult {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input id="searchfield"></input>
<div id="searchresult"></div>
```

Comment: Can I separate the JSON data from the JQuery code? Like have it in seperate files?

Comment: Yes. If you wish not to reveal entire source data, you may do ajax-call to retrieve matching data from server-side.

Comment: how? like this: `$.getJSON( "ajax/data.json", function( data ) {}`

Comment: Official tutorial does that much better than I would do: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'm still not sure what to do, i tried this `$.getJSON( "data.json", function( json ) {
    console.log( "JSON Data name is " + json.name);
});`

Comment: That would be rather something like: `$.getJSON('/url/to/script/doing/search',{search:$(this).val()},function(data){let searchresult=data.map((index,value)=>"<a href=value.url>value.name</a>").join(', ');$('#searchresult').html(searchresult);});` if you prefer shorthand method `$.getJSON()` and forgive my code formatting screwed by SO comments constraints :)

Comment: I've brought up small example (which is bulky and demo purposes only, but more jquery-oriented): https://codesandbox.io/embed/l7085m54wm. That's the best I could do to explain my point:)

Comment: You may accept the answer if that was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use array filter to get the array of objects where the name includes the text that is types in the input. You can put the body of the function `searchValue` inside the `$.each` in your code

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "Senior Officer Trade Back Office",
    "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/senior-officer-trade-back-office-1061445-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=1&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
    "name": "Junior Officer Trade Back Office",
    "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/junior-officer-trade-back-office-1061443-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=2&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
    "name": "5 Machine Learning",
    "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/5-machine-learning-1061442-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=3&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
    "name": "3 Ruby Developers",
    "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/3-ruby-developers-1061441-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=4&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sales Staff (Losgistic - Salary Attractive)",
    "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/sales-staff-losgistic-salary-attractive-1061440-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=5&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
    "name": "5 Front-End Developers",
    "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/5-front-end-developers-2-1061439-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=6&sortBy=date"
  }
]

function searchValue() {
  let srchString = ''
  var searchField = $('#search').val().trim();
  let srchVal = data.filter(val => val.name.includes(searchField))
  srchVal.forEach((item) => {
    srchString += `<li>${item.name}<img src='${item.url}'</li>`

  })
  $('#resultDiv').empty().append(srchString)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='search'>
<input type="button" value='Search' onclick='searchValue()'>
<div id='resultDiv'></div>
```